# What does the Intel USB 3.0 driver installer do differently from a manual installation?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, usb-3

When installing Windows 7, I usually use a driver installer post-installation (specifically [Snappy Driver Installer](https://sdi-tool.org)) to speed up the process of installing them. However, despite a successful message from SDI, my USB 3.0 ports, while working, act as USB 2.0 ports. I’ve confirmed this with a file copy from an external SSD (only reaches 30MBps) and with an external HDD (Toshiba Canvio 3.0) which has an LED indicating whether it’s connected in USB 2.0 or 3.0 mode.

However, if I then use the [Intel USB 3.0 driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/21129) (running the installer), the 3.0 ports function normally and run at full speed.

I’ve been able to repeat this behavior on various Intel based systems (Acer Iconia W700, ASUS Sabertooth Z77, Surface Pro 2). A fresh install of Windows 7 followed by installing the drivers with the files from Intel's ZIP file with device manager causes the same issue, so SDI is not at fault here.

So what does the Intel USB 3.0 driver installer do differently from a manual install? Does it set some sort of registry flag to tell the OS that USB 3.0 ports are available? Could I replicate this behavior?

Comment: My only explaintion, that makes any sense, is that your not installing the the same drivers.  Having a Z77 system myself I have not had the same experiences though, and I have not ran the Intel driver installer, ever on my system but I don't use third-party software to install drivers.

Comment: @Ramhound As I have mentioned in the OP, using device manager to install the drivers from the ZIP file from Intel results in the same behaviour. How did you install your drivers, and was it also on Windows 7?

Comment: Yes; I have ran Windows 7 on my machine in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Intel USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller Driver actually includes 3 drivers inside the Drivers folder of the ZIP file:

```
iusb3hub 
iusb3xhc
iusb3hcs
```

Looking inside the .inf files of the three drivers I noticed this on line 100 of iusb3hcs.inf:

```
XHCI.DeviceDesc = "PCI bus"
```

PCI bus is a device under system devices which already comes with a driver from Microsoft. This explains why I missed it when installing drivers in Device Manager (it did not have a warning sign as it already had a driver) and why SDI missed it while scanning drivers.

To see if this driver was the cause of the issue, I did a fresh install of Windows 7 on an ASUS Sabertooth Z77, followed by updating the drivers of the USB ports with Device Manager and a reboot. As before, the USB 3.0 ports functioned as 2.0 ports. I then updated the driver for PCI bus in Device Manager. After a reboot, the USB 3.0 ports ran at full speed, no Intel installer necessary. This approach has the added benefit of not installing Intel USB 3.0 Monitor, which wastes disk space and CPU cycles.

So as to answer the question, the Intel installer not only installs drivers for the ports, but also updates the PCI bus driver, enabling USB 3.0 in some way in the OS.

Comment: Thank you *so much* for this. I'm running Windows 7 on a MacBook Pro via Boot Camp, and my USB 3.0 has *never* worked properly. Simply clicking PCI bus => Update Driver has fixed the problem!

Answer (score -1):

**DO NOT USE DRIVER INSTALLER PROGRAMS!**  Many of them are scams at worst, installing spyware and viruses.  Even "legitimate" ones are not very good, as they often install the wrong driver.  This is evident, since your SDI program is installing the USB2 driver.

For the average user, letting Windows pick the driver is the best choice.

If Windows cannot find the driver, skip the driver disc that came with the hardware, download the latest driver directly from the hardware manufacturer's website.  This is absolutely the best choice.

Comment: I did a fresh Windows 7 install from DVD and used device manager to install the driver downloaded straight from Intel from the link in OP. The problem still persists. SDI clearly not the problem here.

Comment: This isn't a great answer... borderline and better suited as a comment. Suggest either revising or reposting as a comment.